# There's a way to know which project is executing installer on wix?

Tags: installation, wix

I have two projects that shares a same .wxi file, but now, I need different actions foreach project.

There's a way to know which project is executing installer and change the installer actions on wxi file?

For example,
One project needs shortcut and the second no needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WiX preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm) for doing this: just set a variable, either on the command line or in the main project file before include, and use *conditional statements* to add or to drop some elements.